# Make three MovieClips appear and disappear inside a snowglobe when shaken

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, movieclip

I used a creative cow tutorial to create my own snow globe that moves and snow reactivates - it really is a [great tutorial](https://library.creativecow.net/articles/studios_domani/shake_snow_globe.php/).

What I'm trying to do is Change between 3 Movie clips in the `ActionScript` - But each time I add my movie clip names - Or try and add a simple visibility code I break my snow globe actions.
I have my `MovieClip` instances named friendsSceneThree, BuddiesSceneTwo and HatsOffSceneOne. I would think they'd be good but somewhere I'm missing something. Right now I can't get the code to even SEE The movieclips I'm getting a simple:

```
TypeError: Error #1006: value is not a function.at SnowGlobeContainer/update()
```

Down in the 'if drag' Update is where I'd like to Change from One MClip to the Next.
What Am I Not Seeing?!?!  Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks

Here is the ActionScript:

```
package {



     import flash.display.MovieClip;

     import flash.display.Sprite;

     import flash.events.Event;

     import flash.events.MouseEvent;

     import flash.geom.Rectangle;

     import flash.geom.Point;



     public class SnowGlobeContainer extends Sprite {



              public var snowForeground:SnowGeneratorCircle;

              public var snowBackground:SnowGeneratorCircle;

              public var friendsSceneThree:MovieClip;

              public var buddiesSceneTwo:MovieClip;

              public var hatsOffSceneOne:MovieClip;

              public var drag:Boolean = false;                 

              public var over:Boolean = false;        

              public var startPos:Point = new Point;

              public var mouseDownOffset:Point = new Point;

              public var bounds:Rectangle = new Rectangle;               

              public var vel:Point = new Point(0,0);

              public var pos:Point = new Point(x,y);

              public var old:Point = new Point(x,y);

              public var gravity:Number = 5+(Math.random()*1);

              public var restitution:Number = 0.5;

              public var friction:Number = 0.9;




              public function SnowGlobeContainer() {        

                       // save some initial persistant properties     

                       startPos.x = this.x;

                       startPos.y = this.y;

                       old.x = this.x;

                       old.y = this.y;

                       bounds.x = 0;

                       bounds.y = 0;

                       bounds.width = 600;

                       bounds.height = startPos.y;              

                       // add mouse interaction listeners and show the cursor on rollover

                       this.mouseChildren = false;

                       this.useHandCursor = true;

                       this.buttonMode = true;

                       this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onMouseDown);

                       this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onMouseUp);

                       this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);


              }



              protected function onMouseOver(e:MouseEvent=null):void { over = true; }



              protected function onMouseOut(e:MouseEvent=null):void {  over = false; }



              protected function onMouseDown(e:MouseEvent=null):void {

                       // Save the offset of your mouse when you first start dragging. Same functionality as startDrag(false)

                       mouseDownOffset.x = mouseX;

                       mouseDownOffset.y = mouseY;

                       drag = true;


              }



              protected function onMouseUp(e:MouseEvent=null):void {

                       vel.x = vel.y = 0;

                       pos.x = x;

                       pos.y = y;

                       drag = false; 

              }



              public function update(e:Event):void {

                       // this if/else statement controls the mouse over and out instead of using event listeners


                       if(mouseY < -175 || mouseY > 175 || mouseX < -175 || mouseX > 175){

                                if(over) onMouseOut();

                       }else{

                                if(!over) onMouseOver();

                       }



                       if(drag){

                                // drag around..

                                this.x = parent.mouseX - mouseDownOffset.x;

                                this.y = parent.mouseY - mouseDownOffset.y;

                                // keep this thing on the table :)

                                if(y >= bounds.height) y = bounds.height;

                                // if you "shake" or move the mouse quickly, we are going to reset the snow particles

                                var d:Point = new Point(Math.abs(old.x - x), Math.abs(old.y - y));

                                if(d.x > 50 || d.y > 50 ){

                                         snowForeground.reset();

                                         snowBackground.reset();

                                         friendsSceneThree.visible = false;



                                }                         

                                // update the history position   

                                old.x = x;

                                old.y = y;                               

                                vel.y = (y-old.y)/2;

                       }else{

                                // if you drop this object it should have a bit of realistic falling..

                                vel.y += gravity;

                                pos.y += vel.y;                                         

                                // bounce

                                if(pos.y > bounds.height){

                                         pos.y = bounds.height;

                                         vel.y *= -(Math.random()*restitution);

                                }

                                y = pos.y;

                       }

              }

     }

}
```

I appreciate the help  --  If you haven't noticed I'm new to all of this scripting.  I'm looking in on lynda.com and other forums.  the SnowGeneratorCircle.as is:

```
package {



   import flash.display.Sprite;

   import flash.events.Event;



   public class SnowGeneratorCircle extends Sprite {



        var totalFlakes:int = 500;

        var flakes:Array = new Array();



        public function SnowGeneratorCircle() {

                 addSnowFlakes();

                 addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);

        }



        protected function addSnowFlakes():void{

                 for(var i:int=0; i<totalFlakes; i++){

                          var f:SnowFlake = new SnowFlake();

                          addChild(f);

                          flakes.push(f);                                

                 }

        }



        public function reset():void{

                 for(var i:int=0; i<totalFlakes; i++){

                          var f:SnowFlake = flakes[i];

                          f.reset();

                 }

        }



        public function update(e:Event=null):void {

                 for(var i:int=0; i<totalFlakes; i++){

                          var f:SnowFlake = flakes[i];

                          f.update(0);

                 }

        }
```

}

}

I debugged - didn't clean up the code, because every time I did - it broke the actions.  So I left the code with the double spacing.  That's how it went in when I copied and pasted from the tutorial anyway.
Here's the error on line 173 - which is the MovieClip I'd like to have change.

> Attempting to launch and connect to Player using URL /Volumes/Lacie Biggest S2S/GRaid/Veronica
>   /V/Rubio/Work/SUBARU/SnowGlobe Subaru/SnowGlobeAnima/snowGlobeShakev3.swf
>   [SWF] Volumes:Lacie Biggest S2S:GRaid:Veronica:V:Rubio:Work:SUBARU:SnowGlobe >Subaru:SnowGlobeAnima:snowGlobeShakev3.swf - 468081 bytes after decompression
>   TypeError: Error #1006: value is not a function.
>     at SnowGlobeContainer/update()[/Volumes/Lacie Biggest S2S/GRaid/Veronica/V/Rubio/Work/SUBARU
>   /SnowGlobe Subaru/SnowGlobeAnima/SnowGlobeContainer.as:173]

I just don't know how to get the actionscript to find my MovieClips and then swap them out wt each shake of the globe.

Comment: Can we see your SnowGeneratorCircle Class? It might be the line snowForeground.reset(); You can test this by putting trace(snowForeground.reset); before that line.

Comment: Please format your code better (remove the empty lines, etc.). What line is the error thrown at? Debug your movie instead of simple publish and copy&paste the output. (if you do it in Flash, hit CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER)

Comment: Thanks @Karma, Fygo, Is there a way I can link the project to this so you can take a look?

Comment: What I really need is the code written to make a movie clip appear and disappear.  I've tried to use the Visible function, but the script errors tell me it can't find my clips. (Gives me a Null)